# CS50 Credit Problem is skipping "else if" part

Tags: c, algorithm, cs50, luhn

I am really stuck here. The programm gives right answer to invald credit card numbers but never say if its VISA, AMEX or MASTERCARD.

I need to post the complete code because I do not have so much experience wit the C language.

The checksum part in the end could also have been "bool" but I always got error messages with that.

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
  long long card;
  int checksum = 0;
  do
   {
    card = get_long_long("Number: ");
   }while (card <= 0);


    int count = 0;
    while (card != 0) {
        card /= 10;     // n = n/10
        ++count;
    }

if(count != 16 && count != 13 && count != 15){
      printf("INVALID\n");
  }
  else if(checksum != 0){
      printf("INVALID\n");
   }
  else if(card >= 34e13 || card >= 37e13){
        printf("AMEX\n");
    }
  else if(card >= 51e14 || card >= 52e14 || card >= 53e14 || card >= 54e14 || card >= 55e15) {
       printf("MASTERCARD\n");
           }
  else if(card >= 4e15 || card >=4e12) {
        printf("VISA\n");
        }
  else {
     printf("INVALID\n");
  }
}

int checksum(long long card_nr)
{
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i=0;card_nr !=0; i++, card_nr/=10 )
    {
        if(i % 2 == 0)
            sum += card_nr % 10;
        else
        {
            int digit = 2 * (card_nr % 10);
            sum += digit / 10 + digit % 10;
        }
    }
    return (sum % 10) == 0;
}
```

There may be major issue or only some parenthesis, the programm is compiling. Thanks for any help.

Comment: `else if(card >= 34e13 || card >= 37e13)` Did you mean to do `>=` on both conditions?

Comment: Your conditions seems wonky. `card >= 51e14 || card >= 52e14` for example is odd because if the second part is true, the first must be as well, so there's no point in `card >= 51e14`.

Comment: In the loop: `while (card != 0)` you ensure `card` is zero, and then you use it in your `if` statements without resetting it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many errors with the logic:

````
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
  long long card;
  int checksum = 0;
  do
   {
    card = get_long_long("Number: ");
   }while (card <= 0);


    int count = 0;
    // ** In here you destroy card, so later card whill allways be 0
    while (card != 0) {
        card /= 10;     // n = n/10
        ++count;
    }

if(count != 16 && count != 13 && count != 15){
      printf("INVALID\n");
  }
  else if(checksum != 0){
      printf("INVALID\n");
   }
   //** here it is the same as  if(card >= 34e13)
  else if(card >= 34e13 || card >= 37e13){
        printf("AMEX\n");
    }
   //** here it is the same as  if(card >= 51e14)
   //** also these values are already covered by last check
  else if(card >= 51e14 || card >= 52e14 || card >= 53e14 || card >= 54e14 || card >= 55e15) {
       printf("MASTERCARD\n");
           }
   //** here it is the same as  if(card >= 4e15)
   //** also these values are already covered by previous check
  else if(card >= 4e15 || card >=4e12) {
        printf("VISA\n");
        }
  else {
     printf("INVALID\n");
  }
}

int checksum(long long card_nr)
{
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i=0;card_nr !=0; i++, card_nr/=10 )
    {
        if(i % 2 == 0)
            sum += card_nr % 10;
        else
        {
            int digit = 2 * (card_nr % 10);
            sum += digit / 10 + digit % 10;
        }
    }
    return (sum % 10) == 0;
}```
````

Answer (score 0):

After loop:

```
    while (card != 0) {
        card /= 10;     // n = n/10
        ++count;
    }
```

`card` = 0 and original card number is lost.

You can save original card number to another variable and then compare it.

Also it is better to use integer constants like `54LL << 14` instead of float `54e14`